# wrapping a C printf() call in a preprocessor directive

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor, wrapper, preprocessor-directive

I am attempting to port C code from one platform to another and remove dependencies.

There is a debug function called `dbg_out` which prints out like `printf()`.

The prototype is `void dbg_out(int dbgMask, const char *pFormat, ...);`

Here is an example call : `dbg_out((5, "SerialDriver : (%04x-%08lx) \n", id, sn));`

I would like to map this function to a normal `printf()` call but having some issues.

I have attempted this so far

```
void dbg_out (int dbgMask, const char *pFormat, ...)
__attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)))
;
```

I need to ignore the first parameter dbgMask and just take into consideration the other parameters.

I would prefer to use the preprocessor to define a wrapper. I'd appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Call `vprintf()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using a macro

If you want to use a macro that changes the call to `dbg_out` to a direct call to `printf`, you can use a variadic macro:

```c
#define dbg_out(mask, ...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
  dbg_out(1, "%d", 12);
}
```

if they get called like in your question with double parentheses (e.g. `dbg_out((5, "%d", 12));`
), then you need to unwrap it first:

```c
#define EXPAND(mask, ...) (__VA_ARGS__)
#define dbg_out(...) printf EXPAND __VA_ARGS__

int main() {
  dbg_out((1, "%d", 12));
}
```

---

Additionally if you know that the format is **always a string literal**, you could additionally add the mask to the `printf` output, e.g.:

```c
#define dbg_out(mask, format, ...) printf("[Mask:%d]" format, mask, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
  dbg_out(1, "%d", 12);
}
```

with double parenthesis calls:

```c
#define EXPAND(mask, format, ...) ("[Mask:%d]" format, mask, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define dbg_out(...) printf EXPAND __VA_ARGS__ 

int main() {
  dbg_out((1, "%d", 12));
}
```

#### Redirect to another function with a macro

In case you can't change the implementation of `dbg_out`, you can use a macro to redirect the call to another function that does the work:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>

#define dbg_out(...) dbg_out_new(__VA_ARGS__) 

void dbg_out_new(int mask, const char* fmt, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)));
void dbg_out_new(int mask, const char* fmt, ...) {
  va_list va;
  va_start(va, fmt);
  vprintf(fmt, va);
  va_end(va);
}

int main() {
    dbg_out(1, "%d", 12);
}
```

If it's called with double parenthesis, you need to change the macro to:

```c
#define dbg_out(...) dbg_out_new __VA_ARGS__

/* ... */

int main() {
    dbg_out((1, "%d", 12));
}
```

With the `__attribute__(format())` you also get the benefit of compile-time type checking of the arguments, like in the "Using a macro" example.

#### Change the function

In case you can edit the `dbg_out` function implementation, you could replace it with the above `dbg_out_new` implementation.

However this will not work if it gets called with double parenthesis like you wrote in your question.

Comment: Thanks for all this. Very helpful. In your second last solution, I get the following error which doesn't make sense :  error: expected ';' before 'EXPAND'
 #define dbg_out(...) printf EXPAND __VA_ARGS__

Comment: @Engineer999 are you using the updated version with "##" ? without them it won't work if there's only a format string without additional arguments. If it still doesn't work, could you maybe share the `dbg_out()` invocation that causes problems?

Comment: Actually no errors now.  I am using : #define EXPAND(mask, format, ...) ("[Mask:%d]" format, mask, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define dbg_Printf(...) printf EXPAND __VA_ARGS__   , but getting lots of warnings such as warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long int' .. as not everything i will be printing is a normal int

Comment: @Engineer999 could it be that dbgMask sometimes is passed as a larger int type (e.g. `long` / `long long`)? you could add an explicit cast so it always gets passed as int: `#define EXPAND(mask, format, ...) ("[Mask:%d]" format, (int)mask, ##__VA_ARGS__)`, or change the format specifier to match the passed parameter, e.g. `#define EXPAND(mask, format, ...) ("[Mask:%ld]" format, (long)mask, ##__VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 5):

You need use `vprintf` instead, to be able to use unknown arguments

```
inline void dbg_out (int dbgMask, const char *pFormat, ...) {
  va_list ptr;
  va_start(ptr, pFormat);
  vprintf(pFormat, ptr);
  va_end(ptr);
}
```